# using image map resizer

Tags: javascript, html

I found the following image map resizer so my image map will be responsive:

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer/blob/master/README.md

Following the instructions I placed the following code in the head:

```
<script src="imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

<![endif]-->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie8.polyfil.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

But I don't know where to place the code:

```
imageMapResize([selector || map object]);
```

It says to put it at the bottom of the page. I tried placing it inside of the  and outside the  tag but it's still not working. Where am I supposed to put it??

Comment: I assume that you have **not** used `[selector || map object]` as arguments for `imageMapResize`?!

Comment: It should be wrapped in `<script>` tags, since it is javascript.  You should be able place this code anywhere on the page; in the header, in the body.  I'd put the script tags and this code just before the close body tag (`</body>`).  As was previously mentioned, change `[selector || map object]` to be a selector or map object that you want to resize.

Comment: I have <script>imageMapResize("faith_boosters_map");</script>

just before the close body tag. I've tried it with and without the quotes. faith_boosters_map is the name of the image map. It's not working though.

Comment: It could help, if you add your "image map"-markup too...

Comment: Here's the map:

<img src="images/mobile lower menu2 faith_boosters.png" usemap="#faith_boosters_map">
<map name="faith_boosters_map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="89,41,386,77" href="#" alt="link to Most Insightful Posts">
  <area shape="rect" coords="172,3,471,39" href="#" alt="Link to Emergency Requests">
</map>

Answer (score 1):

You "should" add the script-tag just before the closing body-tag (there are a lot great articles about that topic):

```
    <script></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note, that you have to include a library before you "execute" it ;)

It seems your selector is wrong. Try this:

```
<script>imageMapResize('[name="faith_boosters_map"]')</script>
```

Comment: When I tried this my image map disappeared and there were no links at all. :(

Comment: It is hard to say where your problem sit, without taking a looking deeper in your page.

Answer (score 1):

If you have confusion using vanilla-javascript you could use jquery which is also supported by that library, put the below code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('map').imageMapResize();
     });
</script>
```

Comment: **This library can be used with or without jQuery.** Take a look at the README: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes I know, but thought it would be easy for him.

Comment: Nope, it will make his live much harder, trust me! He will never know what he is doing, without knowing what his code does...

Comment: Okay, I did that and it's now made my image map tiny. At least I think that's what's going on. The map doesn't appear until the width of the browser is under 500px (it's for smart phones). But with the above code the links in the map are tiny and not at all close to the buttons.

Go to http://granthoneymoon.com/temp.html and resize the browser until the lower menu appears above the blank ad. You can tell where the links are supposed to be, but they are tiny and in the upper left corner of the image instead. :-/

Comment: Ah, I think I found the problem. I need to have that on the page BEFORE I create the image map. I'm going to have to redo the image maps, but when I do that it works fine. :)

Comment: In the source of the page you gave I can see you are using rwdImageMaps and not the one you posted